# XCode 4 Analyze configuration?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, static-analysis, analyzer

Is there a way to configure which types of problems the XCode 4 static Analyzer tool reports and doesn't report?

I'm am dealing with some legacy code that "works" but has tons of static analysis issues, and am trying to list certain potentially more critical issues first.

Comment: Have you tried using instruments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience customizing Clang (the static analyzer Xcode uses) myself, but [this blog post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/9/20/disabling-clang-compiler-warnings.html) seems to point to two different change you can make:

1. Turning off some individual warning types in the Build Settings
2. Using `pragma` to ignore specific warnings once you're aware of the right argument

While these options don't really provide any method of "prioritizing" the warnings, you can at least temporarily ignore the ones that you know to be less critical.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4, under project or target Build Settings, near the bottom, are the settings for the Apple LLVM compiler x.0 - Warnings and Static Analyzer - Checkers.  In those build settings, one can turn off or on various warnings that the Product Analyze menu generates, such as report Dead Stores, etc.